# How does the enviroment control of the Arenas work in The Hunger Games?

Tags: the-hunger-games

In the film we see that the Gamemakers can *summon* trees, some sort of hounds, fireballs, etc. How does this work? Can they *summon* anything they want? Are there any restrictions, limitations or rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certain items are already in the Arena as specific objects to be made use of or obstacles to overcome as part of the design for the Arena; since each Arena is designed many years before and the creation of such takes some years.

However there are certain items that are introduced to keep the games "exciting" and whilst you would expect that there are a few of these such as the fireballs that are preplanned, there must be a small arsenal of different weapons of effects that can be called upon at the whim of the Gamemakers.

As to limitations or rules, the only limitations that I can come up with are those that keep the games interesting such as:

- Don't over attack the players (i.e. don't kill them all at once)
- Allow the players who escape time to recuperate
- Don't interfere in existing combat

Other than that there are no rules, anything goes.

Comment: The environmental effects (the fireballs and the fire itself, for example) are intended less to kill and more to bring the tributes together, so that there aren't extended periods with nothing happening. They're also, as you said, pre-defined aspects of the arena, rather than being created on the fly by the Gamemakers.

Comment: But, is it known how can the just make living animals appear? Or a tree fall from the sky?

Comment: @Thecafremo The Gamemakers have access to underground pens containing the animals, and they are released into the arena at a time of the Gamemaker's choosing, which shows both pre-planning and the ability to trigger events.  the tree is basically another of the same.  These events are **extensively** planned.

Comment: Like today's "reality" television and major sports events (the U.S. Superbowl, at least) everything about the Games is scripted to a T. It's very,*very* rare for anything unexpected to happen.